# How can I get values which I have set in admin side system configuratin in magento?

Tags: magento

how to get value from set admin side like system->Configuration->Sales -> Shipping Methods->free shipping-> Minimum Order Amount

Comment: RE closing as O/T: this is why there now is http://magento.stackexchange.com I suppose?

Comment: I'm all for supporting magento.stackexchange.com but I'm not sure why this is "off-topic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get store config value by using this function

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal');
```

`getStoreConfig` is a method to get value of Configuration which we have set in admin.

**carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal** is a path whic stored in database table **core_config_data**.